# Can a write_lock be acquired after a read_lock in Basic Two-phase locking

Tags: database, locking, computer-science, phase

For some S: T1: Read_lock(X), T1: R(X), T1: Write_lock(X), T1: W(X), Unlock(X), Commit

Is this allowed under ***BASIC*** 2PL?

It is my understanding that it isn't...
What does "escalating" a lock mean? I can't seem to find the exact information I'm after.

Comment: Whose definition of 'Basic 2PL'?  Assuming that there are no operations between the unlock and the commit (though it would be better to have the commit do the unlocking), then I don't think there's a problem.  'Escalating' a lock means changing it to a more restrictive locking mode.  There are modes such as 'shared' or 'shared intent exclusive (SIX)' or 'exclusive' which have different implications (for concurrency, mainly).  Shared locks allow other people to read; exclusive locks prevent people reading or writing.  You need to designate which book you're studying, since the answers can vary.